# Vimscript - Previous buffer & propagate error message

Tags: vim, window, buffer

I'm working on a function that opens a help document in the current window, rather than a new split.
This is the function now:

```
function! OpenHelpInCurrentWindow(topic) " {{{2
  " Open a helpfile in the current window, rather than a new split.

  try
  " Open the help document.
    execute 'help '.a:topic

    " Get buffer id of the help document.
    let l:help_buffer = bufnr("%")

    " Close the help buffers' window. This *should* return us to the window we ran
    " this command from.
    wincmd c

    " Switch to the help doc's buffer in the current window.
    :execute "buffer ".help_buffer

  catch
    echo 'Sorry, no help for ' . a:topic . '.'
  endtry

endfunction
```

I map this to :H with:

```
command! -nargs=? -complete=help H call OpenHelpInCurrentWindow(<q-args>)
```

There are currently two issues:

If you enter a bad name for a help file, the help file doesn't open. When using the built-in help command (`:help`) this displays an error message in red, but doesn't require you to hit  to continue.

If I display the error message with `echoerr`, it displays the message in red, but also displays the line number and requires  to continue (not the way `:help` works).

If I display the error message with `echo`, it displays in the foreground color (not red like `:help`, but doesn't display the line number or require  to continue).

Any ideas how I can make this more closely resemble the default behavior?

The second issue is that when you open a help document using this function, the previous buffer is not set correctly. Trying to return to where I was using :bprevious dumps me into the wrong document.

Any ideas why this is occuring, what tracks the 'buffer list' (I don't think this is tagstack), or how I might fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `:echoerr` from within a function prints out multi-line information. The totally correct way would be to move that part out of the function, and put the `:echoerr` directly into the `:command` definition, but it's cumbersome. (My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) has a helpful `ingo#err#Get()` function for that.)

Most plugins instead just use `:echohl` and `:echomsg` to emulate the error reporting:

```
echohl ErrorMsg
echomsg 'Sorry, no help for ' . a:topic . '.'
echohl None
```

The only downside is that it doesn't abort a command chain, e.g. `:H foo | quit`.

---

With regards to `:bprevious`, that navigates by buffer number. As the help buffer is a buffer, too, the order gets messed up. You need to use other navigation means, e.g. the *alternate file* (`<C-^>`, `:edit #`), or arguments and `:argnext`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Answered both questions. To get back to the 'previous' buffer, I should have been using `:blast` (which works as expected).

Answer (score 1):

Forget the window shuffling. We can open help in the current buffer by `set buftype=help`

We have the following problems:

- restore the `'buftype'` value of the previous buffer, `#`, in the success case
- restore the `'buftype'` value of the current buffer, `%`, in the error case
- let the `:h` error message through correctly

The `:h` command like so many of Vim's command will set `v:errmsg` when an error messages occurs. This means we can detect the error message. However as @Ingo Karkat mentioned this will give a "stack trace" when used inside of a function. We can overcome this by suppressing the error via `:silent!`. Now we can check `v:errmsg` and restore `'buftype'` correctly.

Since you still want to keep the error message we will use `:execute` in the `:command` definition and have the function return the failed help command.

Below is the resulting code:

```
function! s:help(subject)
  let buftype = &buftype
  let &buftype = 'help'
  let v:errmsg = ''
  let cmd = "help " . a:subject
  silent! execute  cmd
  if v:errmsg != ''
    let &buftype = buftype
    return cmd
  else
    call setbufvar('#', '&buftype', buftype)
  endif
endfunction
command! -nargs=? -bar -complete=help H execute <SID>help(<q-args>)
```

#### Thoughts

- You may want to look into something like [cmdallias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) to make this command easier to type
- Maybe instead of all this trouble just promote the help window to its own tab via `<c-w>T` (my preference)
- the technique will need to be adjusted to take into consideration if there is a different a window with `buftype=help` already open

#### More help

```
:h 'buftype'
:h :h
:h :silent
:h v:errmsg
:h :exe
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome answer. :) I'm constantly wanting to have a work window open and open a help window (or several) at the same time. I usually have more unused horizontal pixels than vertical, so I use `<C-w>v` to open a vertical split, then `:help <topic>`. Then I go back to the previous window and close it, so I have the original file on the left and the help file now on the right. If I want to look at multiple parts of the file helpfile, then I split it and I can see both with the original file still up. Not that big of a deal, but `:H` saves me a couple keystrokes now. :)

Comment: You may want to look into `:vertical`. e.g. `command -nargs=? -bar H vertical help <args>`. See `:h :vert`